# How to make PMD not counting lines having brackets as lines of code?

Tags: command-line-interface, pmd

How can I make PMD not to count lines just containing curly brackets? For example:

```
public static void countMyLines() {
   int a = 1;
   int b = 2;
   System.out.println("result: "+(a+b));
} // don't count this line
```

I'm using the CLI to check my projects.

Comment: PMD doesn't count lines. But some rules do count statements. Which rule is it you are interested in fine tuning here?

Comment: The rule excessiveclasslength and excessivemethodlength.

Comment: Those rules don't allow any customization as per the official docs. You can always send PRs with the changes.

Comment: How about using [NCSSCount](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_rules_java_design.html#ncsscount) instead of Excessive*Length rules?
See also https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues/2123